# Instagram Stories API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

How can I get the stories from Instagram API?

- I create an app in [instagram developer portal](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)
- I set all the fields in details panel
- I disabled the "Disable implicit OAuth" and "Enforce signed requests" in security panel
- I started a submission in permission panel ( whit video url and description )
- I able to login with instagram
- I able to get the post of logged user

I would get the stories too.
I try the official API according to [Official Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/stories) but i cannot get any stories!!!

How can I get the stories json by api?

Answer (score 1):

The API call below is to get insights

- total exits
- total impressions
- total rach
- total replies
- total taps_forward
- total taps_back

```bash
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/<stories_id>/insights?metric=exits%2Cimpressions%2Creach%2Creplies%2Ctaps_forward%2Ctaps_back&access_token=<token>"
```

Link to Meta docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/insights

The API call below is to get the list of stories ID:

```
curl -i -X GET  "https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/<instagram_id>/stories?access_token=<token>"
```

Link to Meta: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/stories/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use graph API to get stories:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/stories
```

You will only get stories from your account (that is logged in), you should have a active story that is posted within last 24hrs.